# How to sort off-chain

Tags: contract-development, dapps, dapp-development, off-chain

I read [this](https://dev.to/abhinavmir/off-chain-sorting-over-on-chain-sorting-in-solidity-4of7) article about sorting an array on an off-chain backend, but there are some things I can't wrap my head around.

For example, say I have an array of times in no particular order `arr` populated on-chain.
I want to send a copy of `arr` to an off-chain backend to sort the times in order and slice the array so that all the elements before a specified time are deleted. I then want the off-chain backend to send back the copy of `arr` back to the on-chain backend so that `arr` can be updated. My motivation for sending this array off-chain is for gas optimization

How does the off-chain backend "grab" `arr` and return a sorted and sliced version of `arr` specifically? The article mentioned event listeners. Do these listeners and the rest of the off-chain backend have to be programmed in another language (not solidity)? The author of the article doesn't give an example of what an off-chain backend would look like, so I'm not sure how the dynamic would be.

I've heard that people use oracles to access off-chain data. But from what I have seen, most of the data that dapps use from oracles are public data, like market feeds and weather data. Would I need an oracle to grab data from this sort of off-chain backend?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches for making the data available to the backend:

- Using events. Events are cheaper, but the contract cannot access the data to validate so you have to solve that problem in another way (challenge/response, rewards/punishments, etc).
- Store the data in the contract, the data is stored in the contract so it will be able to validate.
- Use the transaction's input to store data, data will be inaccesible to the contract. You need to validate data in a different way.